# What happened to Sidney Leach?

Tags: hellboy

B.P.R.D. agent [Sidney Leach](http://hellboy.wikia.com/wiki/Sidney_Leach), aka the "Human Metal Detector," goes on his first mission in *Wake the Devil*. He shows up again in the subsequent arc *The Chained Coffin and Others*. He makes no further canonical appearances, either in *Hellboy* or *B.P.R.D.*

Given that he is not shown dying and such an early retirement seems unlikely, what happened to him?

Comment: http://hellboy.wikia.com/wiki/Sidney_Leach

Comment: @valorum I've read the page. Unfortunately, the Hellboy wiki is missing a lot of information.